# Housing discrimination example: How do I go about this problem?

Tags: self-study, logistic, econometrics, stata

I have been given a dataset containing the following setup and the following data. Two prospective tenants, one black and one white are looking for apartments across various neighbourhoods. The average incomes of the neighbourhoods are given as well as race of the landlords(1 for black, 0 for white). Both tenants ask at the same houses and their successes(1) and failures(0) are recorded.

How do I relate success of the black and white tenants with income in the neighbourhood?

How do I relate success of the black and white tenants by race of the landlord?

Can I do anything more with the given data?

Stata pointers would also be highly appreciated. I've tried both logit Black(and White) NbdIncm and probit, but I'm not sure which is more appropriate etc. since I have zero experience with such datasets and I'm completely lost. 
github link here raceexample.dta
https://github.com/RT1234-cmd/Data
[image]

Comment: Have you tried Probit regression?

Comment: I need you to expand on this. I'm a noob when it comes to all this.

Comment: Also, this sounds suspiciously like school work since people rarely accept data donations of data from strangers with predefined questions. If that is the case, please add the homework tag.

Comment: This is quite a poor answer.  Consider revising.

Comment: It sounds like you have data from an audit study, where a white and a black applicant apply to the same set of preselected houses. If a landlord accepts the first applicant, does that mean he rejects the second one automatically since the apartment is off the market?

Comment: Adding tag. The (artificial) dataset was given to me by a professor to work through as some holiday self study work, and it's not coursework. Anyway, no, the other applicant in this hypothetical audit isn't automatically rejected since the house isn't 'sold'.

Comment: @StatsStudent can you answer? :(

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: Yeah @Demetri, I just updated the question with a screengrab of the data

Comment: @RT1234 Can you instead just sample the data and link us to the sample?  It would be easier to work directly with the data rather than copy a screen grab.

Comment: @Demetri check raceexample.dta https://github.com/RT1234-cmd/Data

Comment: @RT1234, have you tried reading this in the help section here on how to ask good questions and tell us what you've tried?   https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Especially important and relevant for you will be to read the section on homework questions.  They are welcome but you should tell us what you've tried and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @StatsStudent I've tried both logit Black nbdincome and the same for probit, but the thing is, I'm not sure which is appropriate. Neither have I worked with either logit or probit before (all I know is OLS), so I'm not sure about how to interpret these results either

Comment: Personally I'd avoid probit regression due to the difficulty in interpretability (and there's usually not a large difference between a probit and a logistic regression mode).  You'll definitely want to read up on logistic regression.  There are many excellent tutorials online for free.  You might also want to start a little simpler before you jump right into the modelling phase of your analysis.  Why not create some graphics/visualizations?  I think some bar charts showing the difference in percentage rented by income groups you create might be a useful starting place.

Comment: @StatsStudent The professor who supplied me with the data basically told me to figure out what would be an appropriate tool to use here to basically get me to work with logit models :/ The issue is, the dataset given is weird and I'm not sure it fits well. I really don't know for what values I should conclude the correlation is strong or weak etc. Help in that direction would be appreciated.

Comment: @TR1234, again, stop thinking about models.  You first need to get a feel and understanding of the data.  Do this using basic statistics and visualizations.  Have you done that as a first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code takes a stab at your questions using an OLS model to calculate some means and then plots various kinds of counterfactual predictions from that model. A causal interpretation of this model presumes that you in fact have a decent [audit study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audit_study). Some of your variable labels are inconsistent with the info in the question, so I used the assumption from the questions in cleaning the data. You could make the model richer/different if you had a bigger sample or additional data (including logit/probit). There are comments in the code that explain what each piece does to help you. It assumes that you are familiar with basic linear regression with interactions and prediction.

```
/* (1) Transform the data into long form suitable for modeling */
use "raceexample.dta", clear
gen apt_id = _n
order apt_id NbdIncm LandlordRace
rename (White Black) success_=
reshape long success_, i(apt_id LandlordRace NbdIncm) j(ApplicantRace, string)
rename success_ rented
sencode ApplicantRace, replace
lab define LandlordRace 0 "White" 1 "Black"
lab val LandlordRace LandlordRace
labvarch, trim(0)

/* (2a) Summary statistics & plot the data to get a sense of sample size and shape */
table ApplicantRace LandlordRace , c(mean rented N rented)
tw lowess rented NbdIncm , by(ApplicantRace LandlordRace) ylab(#10, angle(0)) xlab(,grid) adjust name(lowess, replace)

/* (2b) Bin Log Income into Low and High buckets */
xtile income_half = ln(NbdIncm), nq(2)
lab define income_half 1 "Bottom Half" 2 "Top Half"
lab val income_half income_half 
table income_half, c(min NbdIncm  p50 NbdIncm mean NbdIncm max NbdIncm N NbdIncm)

/* (3) Fit a saturated OLS model: analogous to calculating the mean of rented in each cell */
reg rented ib2.ApplicantRace##ib0.LandlordRace##ib1.income_half

/* (4) Plot Predictions with 95% CIs */
/* These corresponds to changing one X, leaving the others as they are */
margins ApplicantRace
marginsplot, ylab(#10, angle(0)) xlab(,grid) name(ar, replace)

margins LandlordRace
marginsplot, ylab(#10, angle(0)) xlab(,grid) name(lr, replace)

margins, at(income_half = (1 2))
marginsplot, ylab(#10, angle(0)) xlab(,grid) name(inc, replace)

/* (5) Consider predictions changing all the variables simultaneously */
margins ApplicantRace#LandlordRace, at(income_half = (1 2))
marginsplot, ylab(#10, angle(0)) xlab(,grid) name(all, replace)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and taking your time! I really appreciate this.

Comment: @RT1234 If this helped, please select it as the answer. If something is not clear, I can clarify in the comments.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov You should probably avoid providing students with solutions to their homework problems.  You should probably guide students, not give them answers...

Comment: @StatsStudent The OP says this was not homework, and I usually take people at their word unless there's a pattern.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see the OP's comments indicating that.  No problem here.